# Ad Banner problems with iframe

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, responsive-design

I checked for a solution to my little problems but nothing worked so far. Hopefully someone could provide a solution for my two problems.

Doing my website with wordpress and not experienced in html and css .. just started to understand the issue I have.

I want to add ad-banners to my website and these are provided from companies either in JS or iframe. I have problems with both but let's start with iFrame. The problem actually is the banners are not responsive at all and even on preview on Laptop with MDPI screen the banners are already cut off on the right side.

The code:

```
<iframe scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;border-style:none;border-style:none;' width='728' height='90' src="https://examplewebsite.world/I?tag=d_565m_79c_&site=565&ad=79" ></iframe>
```

How I changed it:

```
<div class="resp-container">
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://examplewebsite.world/I?tag=d_565m_79c_&site=565&ad=79" ></iframe>
```

Added CSS:

```
.resp-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 56.25%;
```

}

```
.resp-iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
```

}

(This is an example and used for a youtube video the ratio of 9:16 does not fit for padding-top of 56.25% but I tried others and did not work though)

Would be great if someone has an idea .. providers told me they never had this kind of issues with their banners and are not able to help me.

Thank you in advance :)

P.S. I forgot to mention (don't know if this is important). I am using left and right sidebars 20% each so middle content is 60% of the width and the banners should be displayed in the center.

Comment: Firstly, I presume you have an ending `</div>` tag for your `resp-container` div, and you just missed it in your question :)  When you are displaying an iframe, you can resize the iframe itself, but you have no control over the content from the other website. It works with YouTube because their videos are responsive. But if the content isn't responsive then it won't resize to your iframe. It's unlikely the advertiser would want you to make their ad smaller - a 728x90px image will be difficult to read on a 360px mobile screen. This is why they create a range of ads in different sizes & shapes.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question, Yes, I just missed it but I used it when I tried to fix this problem. It seems as you mentioned it. The content is not responsive .. maybe there might be a reason for it but I do not get it. Because if the content of 728x90px remain the same I might go for another banner such as 468x60 for tablet and even using another one for mobile and before these breaking points has been reached the content of the previous banners are quite messed up.

Comment: As I mentioned, the reason is because the ads are static images so when you resize them they will become hard to read - especially if they gets displayed at half it's intended size. The 300x250 or similar sized ads are the most popular size these days because they fit on any screen. You might consider those.

Comment: Hi again, thank you very much for your answer. For mobile devices I will use different sizes now but do you have an idea why these iframe banners 728x90 does not even work on desktop? Just a part of it is displayed and the rest been cut off .. Would be great if you have an idea ..